# Python: unable to convert string into number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I am pulling data from a CSV file, I have data in a column which is showing up as `'7,066'` or `'203,452,512'` The column also has blanks.

I am using Python 3.4 and pandas 0.14.1 (can't use pandas post that because it is making my loops go 50times slower - so need to solve that too separately)

I have tried `pd.read_csv(dtype={'Col1':np.float64})` resulting in error: `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()`

I have also tried `convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` which makes all such numbers into `nan`

Pulling hair here on such a minor issue - have gone through the solutions on the site, but really stuck - thank you very much for taking a look pls.

Comment: try `pd.read_csv` with param `thousands=','` so it recognises the numbers correctly

Comment: sonofagun that did it...

Answer (score 0):

Use split function
eg.

```
x= "7,66,188"
y = x.split(',')
for val in y:
   print int(val)
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks mate - i did thousands as @EdChum (and no @jezrael) suggested and that did it - however, thanks for this too - will note it down.

Comment: Good that you sort out your issue.

Comment: So i tried this out as well.. out put here is
`7\n
66\n
188`

Comment: Print I just kept for check, you can use Val for your purpose

Comment: `In[61]: x= "7,66,188"
In[62]: y = x.split(',')
In[63]: y
Out[63]: ['7', '66', '188']`

am I getting this right? Tx for help again

output should have just been 766188 as a float

Answer (score 0):

You're question isn't much clear - I am presuming you want to have '7,066' or '203,452,512' as numbers (float as you have mentioned trying float64) - you can loop through it, applying the following to each element:

```
>>> val = '7,666,188'
>>> val_num = float(val.replace(',', ''))
>>> val_num
7666188.0
```

Comment: No they are strings which are in that format.. when I applied 'thousands' within the read_csv call, it was able to convert it to floats.. so won't have to use any loops etc